# Expand TD to max available width

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table

I have a `TextBox` and a `Button`. I put them inside the first row of a `table`. What I want is to have the `Button` fixed at 60px and the `TextBox` to take rest of the space. The second row of this `table` has a `TreeView` that should expand to full `table` width. Here's what I have tried:

```
<div class="leftCol">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="FilterTextBox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Width="60" Text="Filter" ID="btnFilter" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TreeView runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" CssClass="leftTreeView" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's the simplistic CSS:

```
.FilterTextBox
{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

The `TreeView` appears okay, but the `TextBox` doesn't seem to expand to full width of the `div` (minus Button's width).

Comment: Have you tried with `width:auto`?

Comment: @Satpal: Just tried that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

set the TD width that contains the button to 60 and the other cell will take up the rest of the space.

```
<div class="leftCol">
 <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="FilterTextBox" />
        </td>
        <td width="60">
            <asp:Button runat="server" Width="60" Text="Filter" ID="btnFilter" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:TreeView runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" CssClass="leftTreeView" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This somewhat works, but the textbox + button widths don't yet fully cover the width of the table.

Comment: I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4LWQ/) for ya. Added border='1' to show that the other cell is indeed taking up the rest of the spacing. Can you post the code after the asp is compiled? Maybe it's some markup from the textbox/button that is preventing what you want.